# How to submit apex:form using apex:actionfunction

Tags: apex, form

I am using apex:form and using apex:commandbutton is not allowing to use fontawesome icon inside that button. So, I want to create a button which will onClick call the apex:actionFunction and will submit that form.

Is it possible to submit the form using apex:actionfunction only not by apex:commandButton? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do this, just make sure you cancel the default action:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="doAction" action="{!someMethod}" />
<button onclick="doAction(); return false;">Do Action!</button>
```

If you don't include a reRender attribute, it behaves mostly like a normal full-form submit, but if you do, it does a partial update of the page. The apex:actionFunction should be within the apex:form you wish to submit.

Comment: I tried using the above it worked for me, but whenever I click the button it is refreshing the whole page, how we can prevent it.

In my case I have a form with input elements and using a button I want to call that action function which will make the request to controller, and if it is completed I have to reRender a specific outputPanel.

But unfortunately it is refreshing the whole page and reRender is not working for the same,

Please suggest a better way to achieve this scenario. It will be very helpful to me.

Thanks,

Comment: @PrateekKumar the reRender should work. Make sure you're cancelling the default form submit.